# C++ serialization - use of reinterpret_cast from char * to a struct

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, deserialization

I am exchanging a struct called `struct update_packet` with other servers (of identical or similar system) running the same program through `UDP` socket using `sendto(..)` and `recvfrom()`.

`update_packet` needs to be in the general message format, which means its fields has predetermined fixed size and the size of the struct is the sum of the fields.

```
struct node {
    uint32_t IP;
    uint16_t port;
    int16_t nil;
    uint16_t server_id;
    uint16_t cost;
};

struct update_packet {
    uint16_t num_update_fields;
    uint16_t port;
    uint32_t IP;

    struct node * nodes;

    update_packet() :
        num_update_fields(num_nodes), IP(myIP), port(myport)
        {//fill in nodes array};
};
```

(`update_packet` contains a pointer array of `struct node`)

I used `reinterpret_cast` to send an instance of `update packet` via UDP, and the following compiles and sends to the correct destination.

```
int update_packet_size = sizeof(up);
sendto(s, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&up), update_packet_size, 0,
       (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));
```

However, when I receive it and try to decode it by

```
struct update_packet update_msg =
    reinterpret_cast<struct update_packet>(recved_msg);
```

I get an error

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
error: invalid cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘update_packet’
           struct update_packet update_msg = 
           reinterpret_cast<struct update_packet>(recved_msg);
```

Why does this error occur, and how can I fix this?

Also, is this a correct way to exchange data in an instance of `struct` through sockets? If not, what should I do? Do I need a `pack()`ing function like in http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/pack2.c ?

Comment: In C++ `struct` types can be referred to independently, no need of the `struct` qualifier i.e. you can simply write `update_packet` instead of `struct update_packet`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Generalities**

The cast issue has been properly answered in other questions.

However, you should never rely on pointer cast for sending/receiving a struct through the network, for many reasons including:

- Packing : the compiler may align struct variables and insert padding bytes. This is compiler dependent, thus your code will not be portable. If the two communicating machines run your program compiled with different compilers, it will likely not work.
- Endianness : for the same reason, the byte order when sending a multibyte number (such as int) may be different between the two machines.

This would be resulting in a code which might work for some times, but a few years later which would cause a lot of problems, if someone changes the compiler, the platform, etc... As this is for an educational project you should try doing it the proper way...

For this reason, converting data from a struct into a char array for sending through the network or writing to file should be done carefully, variable by variable, and if possible taking endianness into account. This process is called "serializing".

**Serialization in details**

Serialization means you convert a data structure into an array of bytes, that can be sent over the network.

The serialized format is not necessarily binary : text or xml are possible options. If the amount of data is small, text is maybe the best solution, and you can rely on the STL only with stringstreams (std::istringstream and std::ostringstream)

There are several good libraries for serializing to binary, for instance Boost::serialization or QDataStream in Qt.
You may also do it yourself, look SO for "C++ serializing"

**Simple serializing to text using the STL**

In your case, you might just serialize to a text string using something like:

```
std::ostringstream oss;

oss << up.port;
oss << up.IP;
oss << up.num_update_fields;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<up.num_update_fields;i++)
{
    oss << up.nodes[i].IP;
    oss << up.nodes[i].port;
    oss << up.nodes[i].nil;
    oss << up.nodes[i].server_id;
    oss << up.nodes[i].cost;
}

std::string str = oss.str();

char * data_to_send = str.data();
unsigned int num_bytes_to_send = str.size();
```

And for deserializing received data:

```
std::string str(data_received, num_bytes_received);
std::istringstream(str);


update_packet up;
iss >> up.port;
iss >> up.IP;
iss >> up.num_update_fields;
//maximum number of nodes should be checked here before doing memory allocation!
up.nodes = (nodes*)malloc(sizeof(node)*up.num_update_fields);
for(unsigned int i=0;i<up.num_update_fields;i++)
{
    iss >> up.nodes[i].IP;
    iss >> up.nodes[i].port;
    iss >> up.nodes[i].nil;
    iss >> up.nodes[i].server_id;
    iss >> up.nodes[i].cost;
}
```

This will be 100% portable and safe. You may verify data validity by checking the iss error flags.

Also you might, for safety:

- Use a std::vector instead of the node pointer. This will prevent memory leaks and other issues
- Check the number of nodes just after `iss >> up.num_update_fields;`, if it's too big just abort the decoding before allocating a huge buffer that will crash your program and maybe the system. Network attacks are based on "holes" like that : you may cause the a server to crash by making him allocate a buffer 100x larger than its RAM, if this kind of check is not made.
- If your networking API has a std::iostream interface, you may use directly the << and >> operators from it, without using the intermediate string and stringstreams
- You might think using space separated text is a waste of bandwidth. Think this only if your number of nodes is large, and makes the bandwidth use become non-negligible and critical. In that case, you need to serialize to binary. But don't do it if the text solution works perfectly (beware of premature optimization!)

**Simple Binary serialization** (not byte-order/endianness aware):

Replace:

```
oss.write << up.port;
```

By:

```
oss.write((const char *)&up.port, sizeof(up.port));
```

**Endianness**

But in your project, Big-Endian is required. If you are running on a PC (x86) you need to invert bytes in every field.

1)First option : by hand

```
const char * ptr = &up.port;
unsigned int s = sizeof(up.port);
for(unsigned int i=0; i<s; i++)
    oss.put(ptr[s-1-i]);
```

Ultimate code : detect endianness (this is not difficult to do - look for it on SO) and adapt your serialization code.

2)Second option : use a library like boost or Qt

These libraries let you choose the endianness of the output data. Then they auto-detect the platform endianness and do the job automatically.

Comment: A requirement for this project is that the update packet has a fixed size (32*2 bits for header and 32*3 for each `node`). XML obviously adds more bits to this, so I cannot use it. Also, in this case I guess the output from serialization should be binary with the same size. I wonder how this is done. For example, a 16 bit integer with decimal value, say, 500 is 00000001 00101100 in `uint16_t`. How is this converted to a string that takes 16 bits, when 1 char takes 8 bits?

Comment: Well. Never mind. I think I'm still not clear about the project specification

Comment: By the way what should I do about the node array in the `struct node`? An array is a pointer to an address and sending a pointer to the other machine is meaningless, so should I make a char * that contains data for `node`s in that array, and serialization is the way to do it?

Comment: Yes. The simple/safest way is likely to convert all your data to text with a space separator, using ostringstream and the << operator. For the node array, just output the number of nodes, followed by the content of every node sequentially.

Comment: If I cannot afford to use a space separator, is it safe to use the size of data type when retrieving the data? (it's going to be very complex.. is there any trick to do this simply?) The `num_update_fields` field is actually the number of `struct node`s, so maybe I could use this to retrieve serialized data of `struct node`s.

Comment: Why cannot you afford the text+space separator? Is network bandwidth a strong constraint? I have put code for (de)serialization using only the standard library above

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I understood the picture in the first link as an `update packet` should have strictly a size (32 * 2) + (32 * 3) * number of `node`s.

Comment: OK so the serialization is required by the specifications. By the way, did they specify the byte order/endianness? If not, ask them, they will be impressed... You need to serialize to binary

Comment: Big Endian is required

Comment: I just saw the sample code in your answer. I really appreciate it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which platform are you working on? x86 PCs are Little-Endian... This would mean you have to invert byte per byte

Comment: Oh I just found out my local machine uses little endian, and also the school server for testing also uses little endian

Comment: Oh my god... I didn't even know that a thing called serialization even existed until a few days ago, and then this project is going to be so much complicated than I expected.. but your answer really helps.. I will study them thoroughly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast a pointer to a struct, but you can cast a pointer to a pointer to a struct.

Change

```
struct update_packet update_msg = 
       reinterpret_cast<struct update_packet>(recved_msg);
```

to

```
update_packet * update_msg = 
       reinterpret_cast<update_packet *>(recved_msg);
```

And yes, you need, at least `pack()` because the compiler on the sending side might add padding differently. However it is not 100% safe. You also have take into account that the sending and receiving machine differ in endianess. I would suggest that you look into proper serialization mechanisms.

Comment: Packing is compiler dependant and not portable. Relying on it for serialization is lazy, properly serializing to a char array, despite requiring more code, offers better control, solves endianness issues, and is much more portable and safer.

Comment: Portability is not an issue because it's just a school project and all fields need to be in Big endian. Your solution works for int fields in `update_packet`, but can I ask one more question? I have a pointer array of `struct node` inside `update_packet`. I tried to reference an element of this array `nodes` by update_msg->nodes[0]->cost, `update_msg->nodes->cost`, etc., however they failed. I thought having a pointer array in a message could be problematic, but do you know what exactly is a problem?

Comment: Well I'd say the opposite... If it's for education, learn the clean way to do reliable things. If it's for a space launch, use clean and reliable code. If it's for a toilet paper factory engineering development, use clean and reliable code to avoid someone debugging your code in 10 years when the OS has changed.

Comment: And for a school project, if you will be noted on the code, you will have a better note with state of the art serialization (especially if other students did it the crappy way)

Comment: Edited : this is not undefined behavior, you are lucky in this case! But I bet you did not check this (see type aliasing rules section) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Comment: @galinette No, this **is** un/implementation-defined behaviour, since OP is reading a `char` buffer as a `MyStruct`, whereas the Standard only explicitly allows the _converse_. Many compilers allow this, and happily produce the results that many users intuitively expect, but that doesn't mean it's defined by the standard - it is not.

Comment: @underscore_d : you are right it is UB, since the pointer was allocated as a char array from the networking library. But all compilers (not only many) must allow converting a char* to another pointer, since the standard explicitely states that reinterpret_casting T* to char* then back to T* is defined.

Comment: @galinette Can you show us where this is explicitly allowed? **5.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]** does not mention `char` at all. And, again, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast for example only provisions for conversion _from_ `char *` to `OtherObj`.

Comment: @galinette I know more now, so I can clarify my last comment/strengthen yours. The converse rule I mentioned is a bit orthogonal. You're right that "it is UB, since the pointer was allocated as a char array" - so the `struct`'s alignment requirements are not guaranteed => UB. And a naive 'address value' cast from `char *` must be allowed to enable 'round trips' - but for the same reason, that does **not** mean any `char *` can be cast to any object. Casting `char *` to `T *` is only defined for round trips where said `char *` was itself obtained from a valid `T *` - which is not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use:

```
struct update_packet update_msg;

memcpy(&update_msg, recved_msg, size-of-message);
```

You must however ensure that `size-of-message` is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This is **the** way to do anything like this, as it ensures the (necessarily trivially copyable) destination is properly aligned and alive - unlike the frequently cited, horribly undefined attempts to `reinterpret_cast` some `char *` to _an unaligned imaginary object that doesn't exist_ in terms of the object model. Plus, if the native platform and compiler support it, the _as-if_ rule means they can completely legally optimise the `struct` instance and accesses to it into the same hacky, potentially unaligned casting _anyway_ - assuming there would be sufficient material benefit from doing so

Answer (score 1):

Speaking just of decoding (your computer - your rules), both endianness and packing can be taken into account on GCC and Clang with a combo like this (it's using the [Boost.Endian](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html) library):

```
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
using boost::endian::big_uint16_t;
using boost::endian::big_uint32_t;
using boost::endian::big_uint64_t;

#pragma pack(push, 1)

enum class e_message_type: uint8_t {
  hello = 'H',
  goodbye = 'G'
};

struct message_header {
    big_uint16_t size;
    e_message_type message_type;
    std::byte reserved;
};
static_assert(sizeof(header) == 4);

struct price_quote {
  big_uint64_t price;
  big_uint32_t size;
  big_uint32_t timestamp;
};
static_assert(sizeof(header) == 16);

template<class T> struct envelope {
  message_header header;
  T payload; 
};
static_assert(sizeof(envelope<price_quote>) == 20);

#pragma pack(pop)

// and then
auto& x = *static_cast<envelope const*>(buffer.data());
```